# Pet bottles force-carbonation

Tags: bottles, force-carbonation

I use to prime my PET bottles with dextrose and carbonation is usually good.  My last batch did not carbonate well (for reasons that I am investigating...), I will fix this, but my question is about other ways to carbonate my PET bottles.

I'm thinking about kegging in the future, but I don't want to buy everything right now.  So could I buy the following :

- 5lbs CO2 tank
- a regulator
- PET bottle carbonation cap [like this one](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01IK9NYTG/ref=s9u_simh_gw_i2?ie=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B01IK9NYTG&pd_rd_r=AJZ7JSEGN67BYAXNRH61&pd_rd_w=NDD27&pd_rd_wg=Pk0xA&pf_rd_m=A3DWYIK6Y9EEQB&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=5DGG845FJNFNCW1TR01P&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=04ba9dff-ad6f-4c0e-9daf-7ccc545ca71b&pf_rd_i=desktop)

Then, I could fill my PET bottle with CO2.  But how does it work?  Is it reliable? Can you guide me on the process?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get a ball lock attachment for plastic bottles, then force carbonate as you would a keg. 12-15psi for a few days.

Comment: Let's say I use 1L and 500ml bottles, I need a few days connected on each?  Then I put a regular screw cap on?

Comment: For the plug and forget method yes. But you could also attach and gently rock the bottles at normal pressure. When they stop taking co2, they are fully carbed. Usually in less than 20 minutes.

Comment: Liquids will carbonate better at cooler temperatures. So cooling the filled bottles in the fridge (or, with care, in the freezer) will help with "forced carbonation".